# Converting PDFs to images in Python with Poppler, but Poppler doesn't register as being in PATH?

Tags: python, pdf, poppler

I have very little to say about this issue so hopefully this is a known problem and I'm just bad at finding previous threads about it. In any case, as the title states, I'm trying to convert PDF files to sets of images in bulk (for right now I'd like it to work for just one conversion though).

I'm trying to use a wrapper for poppler (pdf2image), but when I attempt to run the conversion, I get the following error:

> Exception: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

I installed poppler and added it to PATH, but I still get the error. What gives? And additionally, is there a more succinct/better way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

try to add poppler/bin in system variable path

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly add the path in `convert_from_path` function of module `pdf2image`

Example==>
`pages = pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf_file, poppler_path='your_path')`

works just fine and you don't worry about adding it to system path variables.